# Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, database

I recently upgraded my database MySQL version form 5.4.something to 5.5.49
to adjust with woo commerce. I also imported & exported the whole database in a new one. 
Now I'm getting this error on one of my page

> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'yury97'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/yury97/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada/template-member_list.php on line 22
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/yury97/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada/template-member_list.php on line 22
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/yury97/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada/template-member_list.php on line 27

Comment: is that you have imported users?

Comment: Did you also upgrade PHP?

Comment: Yes I also upgrade php version. 5.6.25

Comment: any solution please

Answer (score 0):

Which version you are using PHP mysql_query() is old function and new one 
mysqli_query() http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php password might be wrong have you checked?

Comment: What can I do now? My current php version is 5.6.25

Comment: After upgrading php I exported my database from php myadmin & then created a new database then imported again & after all declared new user & password at wp-config.php